# Add to array from List<string>

Tags: c#, list

How add to

```
GroupAtributes = new GroupAttribute[]
{
    new GroupAttribute { value = groupName },
    new GroupAttribute { value = groupName },
    new GroupAttribute { value = groupName }
};
```

from `List<string> groupNames`?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but you can never *add* to arrays - you can create a new array, or replace the values of existing elements, but once an array is created, its size is fixed. If you could explain the bigger picture, we're more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can't add to an array. The array is allocated to hold three items. If you want to add more items, you have to resize the array so that it will hold more items. Look at [Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) for more info.

But why not just replace that array with a `List<GroupAttributes>`? You can build it as a list and then if you really need an array, you can call `ToArray` on the list.

Does this do what you want?

```
List<GroupAttribute> attrList = new List<GroupAttributes>();
// here, put a bunch of items into the list
// now, create an array from the list.
GroupAttribute[] attrArray = attrList.ToArray();
```

That last statement creates an array from the list.

**Edit:** It occurs to me that maybe you want something like this:

```
var GroupAttributes = (from name in groupNames
                       select new GroupAttribute{value = name}).ToArray();
```

Comment: If I want add to GroupAtributes = new GroupAttribute[]
{
    new GroupAttribute { value = groupName }
}; all items from groupNames

Comment: @zrab: As has been explained to you, you can't. Once you've got an array, the size of that array is fixed. You can create a *new* array (and reassign the value of the existing variable to refer to it) but you can't add to the *old* array.

Comment: @zrab: Perhaps my latest update was what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get the `ToArray` method of the list working, or you can use a more classic approach such as ( I did not try to compile so it might need adjustments )

```
GroupAtributes[] myArray = new GroupAttribute[groupNames.Count]

int i=0; 
foreach(var name in groupNames)
{
    myArray[i++] = new GroupAttribute { value = name };
}
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much. But I have new a similar problem. listObject - ObservableCollection which contains Caption, FileName, MappingName properties. I want add items from this collection to package.PrepareAtributes = new PrepareAttribute[] { new PrepareAttribute { Caption = captionValue, FileName = fileNameValue, MappingName = MappingNameValue }

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not designed for 'adding', but it has its uses if you don't want a list to overallocate memory (usually this is at the expense of speed).

```
    public void Add<T>(ref T[] ar, List<T> list)
    {
        int oldlen = ar.Length;
        Array.Resize<T>(ref ar, oldlen + list.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
        {
            ar[oldlen + i] = list[i];
        }
    }
```

Then simply call Add(ref attrs, myAttrsList);